# SQLAlchemy filtering a composite key table from subquery of itself

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a subquery for a larger query. One table has some details while the second table is used for many-to-many relation ship joins. The second table is filtered using an inner join with itself.

(I am using flask to create my ORM classes as this is for a flask application)

```
class Details(db.Model):
    ck_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('CompositeKey.id'), primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(6), primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Numeric(3, 2))
```

```
class CompositeKey(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    guid = db.Column(db.String(12), db.ForeignKey('other_table.guid'), primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, primary_key=True)

    detail = db.relationship('Details', backref='issue')
```

The raw sql works as expected:

```
SELECT ck1.guid,  ck1.date, d.key, d.value
FROM CompositeKey AS ck1
INNER JOIN Details AS d
ON ck1.id = d.ck_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ck2.guid, MAX(ck2.date) AS "latest_date"
    FROM CompositeKey AS ck2
    WHERE ck2.date <= 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    GROUP BY ck2.guid
) AS ck2
ON ck1.guid = ck2.guid AND ck1.date = ck2.latest_date
```

starting from the inside, I have created a subquery to filter for the latest date in the compositekey table.

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from models import CompositeKey as ck
from models import Details as d

date_param = "YYYY-MM-DD"

inner_subquery = select(
            ck.guid,
            func.max(ck.date).label("latest_date")
            ).\
            where(
            ck.date <= date_param
            ).\
            group_by(ck.guid).\
            subquery()

outer_subquery = select(
            ck.guid,
            ck.date,
            d.key,
            d.value
            ).\
            join_from(from_=ck, target=d).\
            group_by(ck.guid)  # .\
            #  subquery() << commented out for testing. Add it back once the inner subquery is joined.
```

Alone, both of these work as expected. The problem is that the `outer_subquery` is not filtered by the most recent date. I need to somehow join the `outer_subquery` with the `inner_subquery`. It's pretty simple in raw sql but for whatever reason I am struggling to find the right calls. Maybe I am missing some fundamental differences between ORM joins and SQLAlchemy core joins?

pseudo-ish code that I think I am trying to achieve.

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

onclause_ = and_(outer_subquery.c.guid == inner_subquery.c.guid, outer_subquery.c.date == inner_subquery.c.latest_date)

full_subquery = select("*").\
                    join_from(outer_subquery, inner_subquery, onclause_).subquery()
```